# Restrict the type of Tasks a User Role can run in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I am currently looking into airflow to allow a set of users to define & run some basic processes. However I would like to restrict the types of Tasks that those users are allowed to run. For example I do not want them to be able to use the BashOperator.

I have seen the access control documentation, but it appears to only show access permissions for Task Instances that have executed in a DAG. Does anyone know how I can implement this?

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/access-control.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to limit operators to selected user roles at the moment, but you can limit operators for all users using a task policy: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/cluster-policies.html?highlight=cluster%20policy#task-policies:

```py
def task_policy(task: BaseOperator):
    if task.task_type == 'BashOperator':
        raise AirflowClusterPolicyViolation("BashOperator not permitted")
```

Comment: thanks, limiting it at the cluster level will be fine for me